# Using angular-translate on a template loaded asynchronously

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I am using [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/) on an app. It uses tabs that can switch its contents dynamically with the help of [angular-ui](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/), I get the content through a custom service that uses $http.

The template is then sanitised and pushed into an array for later rendering:

```
 var addNewTab = function(template, tabClass) {
   var id = $scope.tabs.length + 1;
   tabClass = tabClass || '';
   template = $sce.trustAsHtml(template);
   template = $compile(template)($scope);

   $scope.tabs.push({
     id: id,
     name: 'PLACEHOLDER TITLE',
     active: true,
     content: template,
     tabClass: tabClass
   });
 };
```

In the view it is rendered with {{tab.content}}, everything up to this point works quite well, the problem I have is getting angular-translate to translate the newly inserted template.

Inside the template I am using the translate directive to translate things but since the template is outside the $scope of wherever translations happen, its texts are not being rendered.

I thought I could get it to work using $compile but I don't quite get how to use it.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.